# Vue 2: computed свойство компонента не получает значение getters из vuex

Tags: vue.js, vuex, getter

Всем здравствуйте.
Корзина покупок. Конфигурация пациента - никаких сборщиков, все в одном файле. При загрузке приложения хранилище vuex асинхронным actions получает с сервера данные каталога товаров (Ок), инициализирует корзину покупок покупателя (localstorage или {})(Ок). Дальше работа с корзиной идет синхронно, поэтому actions больше не использую, действую через mutations.
Для отслеживания и тестирования использую vue.devtools Chrome
Вот код хранилища:

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        customerId: null,
        products: {},
        cart: {},
    },

    getters: {
        products: state => state.products,
        customerId: state => state.customerId,
        //cart: state => state.cart,
        searchProductsTitle: (state) => (productSearchedTitle) => {
            result = {}
            if (typeof productSearchedTitle !== 'undefined' && productSearchedTitle != '') {
                let m_count = Object.keys(state.products).length
                let keys = Object.keys(state.products)
                for (i = 0; i < m_count; i++) {
                    let product = state.products[keys[i]]
                    if (product.title.toLowerCase().includes(productSearchedTitle.toLowerCase())) Vue.set(result, i, product)
                }
            }
            return result
        },
        cart_sum: state => {
            sum = 0.00
            let m_count = Object.keys(state.cart).length
            let keys = Object.keys(state.cart)
            for (i = 0; i < m_count; i++) {
                let item = state.cart[keys[i]]
                sum += item[0]['opd'] * item[1]
            }

            return sum
        }
    },

    mutations: {
        'CUSTOMER_ID' (state, id) {
            state.customerId = id;
        },

        'SET_STORE' (state, products) {
            state.products = products
        },

        'SET_CART' (state, cart) {
            state.cart = cart
            localStorage.shoppingcart = JSON.stringify(state.cart)
        },

        'ADD_TO_CART' (state, data) {
            let id = data[0]['id']
            let amount = data[1]

            let item = state.cart[id]
            if (typeof item == 'undefined') {
                item = [data[0], amount]
            } else {
                item[1] += amount
            }

            Vue.set(state.cart, id, item)
            localStorage.shoppingcart = JSON.stringify(state.cart)
        },

        'REMOVE_FROM_CART' (state, data) {
            let id = data[0]['id']
            let amount = data[1]

            let item = state.cart[id]
            if (typeof item != 'undefined') {
                if (item[1] > amount) {
                    item[1] -= amount
                    Vue.set(state.cart, id, item)
                } else {
                    Vue.delete(state.cart, id)
                }
                localStorage.shoppingcart = JSON.stringify(state.cart)
            }
        },


    },

    actions: {
        initStore: async ({commit}, id) => {...},

    },

});
```

Компонент, работающий с хранилищем:

```
const ShoppingCart = {
    template: `
        <div id="shopping-cart">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col"> </th>
                        <th scope="col">Title</th>
                        <th scope="col">Price</th>
                        <th scope="col">Amount</th>
                        <th scope="col">Sum</th>
                        <th scope="col"> </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="(item, index) in cart" v-bind:key="index">
                        <th scope="row"><img :src="item[0]['media_url']" width="32px" height="32px"></th>
                        <td>{{ item[0]['title'] }}</td>
                        <td>&#8362; {{ item[0]['opd'] }}</td>
                        <td class="form-inline">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" @click="decrCart(item[0], index)"></i></button>
                            <input class="form-control form-control-sm" type="text" v-model:value="item[1]" readonly size="2" style="text-align: center;">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary my-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" @click="incCart(item[0], index)"></i></button>
                        </td>
                        <td>&#8362; {{ (item[0]['opd'] * item[1]).toFixed(2) }}</td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-outline-danger my-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" @click="removeCart(item[0])"></i></button></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <thead class="thead-light">
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" colspan="4"> </th>
                        <th scope="col">&#8362; {{ (this.totalsum).toFixed(2) }}</th>
                        <th scope="col"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
            </table>
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="go-purchase" :disabled="totulproducts == 0">Go to Purchase!</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" id="clear-cart" @click="remove_all()">Remove all</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    `,

    computed: {
        cart() {
            return store.state.cart
        },

        totalsum() {
            return store.getters.cart_sum;
        },

        totulproducts() {
            return Object.keys(this.cart).length;
        }

    },

    methods: {
        remove_all() {
            store.commit('SET_CART', {});
        },

        incCart(item, index, amount=1) {
            store.commit('ADD_TO_CART', [item, amount]);
        },

        decrCart(item, index, amount=1) {
            store.commit('REMOVE_FROM_CART', [item, amount]);
        },

        removeCart(item) {
            store.commit('REMOVE_FROM_CART', [item, 10000]);
        }

    },

    data: function() {
        return {

        }
    },

}
```

**А теперь описание проблем**

1. При нажатии кнопок + и - для уменьшения или увеличения единиц товара в корзине devtools показывает изменение количества в секции vuex, но не фиксирует это в секции Computed cart для компонента (кстати, при переключении вкладов Vue.devtools состояние компонента сразу же обновляется!). При этом нажатие на кнопку "Удалить товар из корзины полностью" работает отлично, сразу же чистит и vuex, и компонент, и отрисовку компонента. Аналогичная правильная реакция в ситуации, когда количество уменьшается до нуля.
   Не работает именно в части подсчетов на уже имеющемся в корзине товаре.
2. Не происходит пересчет общей суммы корзины (даже после переключения вкладок vue.devtools или переключения на FE между каталогом и корзиной - то есть переключением динамических компонентов - при этом состояние корзины меняется на правильное, то есть при начальной загрузке компонент это из корзины читает, а общая сумма, получаемая по геттеру - нет, не меняется).
3. Даже при обновлении состояния корзины в vue.devtools отрисовка на FE не меняется.

Что-то мне подсказывает, что эти 3 проблемы связаны более чем тесно, но не получается самому решить. Перебрал массу вариантов, но вынужден просить помощи коллективного разума.

Comment: Вы сначала вызываете action (через .dispatch()), а потом мутацию в нем, а не мутацию напрямую. Vue.set должен работать нормально. Но вообще, конечно, полностью воспроизводимый пример, а не кусками...

Comment: Vladimir, я как раз сейчас пробовал отрабатывать такой вариант - но постоянно падал на ошибку. Сейчас попробую еще раз заново напишу короткий actions для vuex, который будет вызывать мутацию...может, просто синтаксис был в прошлый раз.

Comment: vue.js?ver=2:634 [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: sub is not a function"

found in

---> <ShoppingCart>
       <LoggedIn>
         <Root>

store.dispatch('increment', [item, amount]); 

  increment(context, data ) {
   context.commit('ADD_TO_CART', data);
  },

Comment: Ну ошибка эта мало о чем говорит без кода, или где-то что-то не так пишите, или не так как-то обращаетесь. `sub` у Вас откда берется, найдите

Comment: да нет там никакого sub, вот в чем дело - я поиском полностью весь код еще раз проверил, sub только в состав слов входит типа @submit etc. Код всего файла 928 строк.  код управления vuex и одного этого компонента, конечно, короче. Подскажите, как показать....

Comment: Более того: сейчас из метода компонента я вообще убрал все, кроме store.dispatch('increment), даже параметр не передаю! В actions increment также убрал полностью все, то есть заголовок и пустота между { } - а ошибка все равно есть. Как только перестаю обращаться к dispatch - она пропадает...

Comment: кроме того, опираясь на документацию vuex, нет никакой необходимости использовать действия для синхронных операций - я имею полное право вызвать напрямую мутацию. Так что возвращаемся к вопросу, почему изменение в vuex не приводит к реактивному обновлению в компоненте computed...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос полностью решен. По ходу дела также выполнен рефакторинг системы работы с корзиной - в частности, вместо того, чтобы хранить в ней дубли продуктов, сейчас корзина только количество продуктов, с совпадающим id.

Вот отрефактореченный код Vuex:

```
Vue.use(Vuex);

const store = new Vuex.Store({
state: {
    customerId: null,
    customer: {},
    products: {},
    idcart: {},
},

getters: {
    products: state => state.products,
    customerId: state => state.customerId,

    cartAll: state => {
        let m_count = Object.keys(state.idcart).length
        let keys = Object.keys(state.idcart)
        let cart = {}
        for (i = 0; i < m_count; i++) {
            cart[keys[i]] = {'product': state.products[keys[i]], 'amount': state.idcart[keys[i]]}
        }
        return cart
    },

    cartById: state => id => {
        return {'product': state.products[id], 'amount': state.idcart[id]}
    },

    searchProductsTitle: (state) => (productSearchedTitle) => {
        result = {}
        if (typeof productSearchedTitle !== 'undefined' && productSearchedTitle != '') {
            let m_count = Object.keys(state.products).length
            let keys = Object.keys(state.products)
            for (i = 0; i < m_count; i++) {
                let product = state.products[keys[i]]
                if (product.title.toLowerCase().includes(productSearchedTitle.toLowerCase())) Vue.set(result, i, product)
            }
        }
        return result
    },

    cart_sum: state => {
        sum = 0.00
        let m_count = Object.keys(state.idcart).length
        let keys = Object.keys(state.idcart)
        for (i = 0; i < m_count; i++) {
            sum += state.products[keys[i]]['opd'] * state.idcart[keys[i]]
        }

        return sum
    },

    customerName: state => state.customer['name'],
    customerStatus: state => state.customer['user_status'],

    customerApproval: state => {
        (state.customer['approval_status'] == 1)
    },
},

mutations: {
    'CUSTOMER_ID' (state, id) {
        state.customerId = id;
    },

    'SET_CUSTOMER' (state, customer) {
        state.customer = customer
    },

    'SET_STORE' (state, products) {
        state.products = products
    },

    'SET_CART' (state, cart) {
        state.idcart = cart
        localStorage.shoppingcart = JSON.stringify(state.idcart)
    },

    'ADD_TO_CART' (state, data) {
        let id = data[0]['id']
        let amount = data[1]

        if (typeof state.idcart[id] == 'undefined') {
            Vue.set(state.idcart, id, amount)
        } else {
            state.idcart[id] += amount
        }
        localStorage.shoppingcart = JSON.stringify(state.idcart)

    },

    'REMOVE_FROM_CART' (state, data) {
        let id = data[0]['id']
        let amount = data[1]

        if (typeof state.idcart[id] != 'undefined') {
            if (state.idcart[id] > amount) {
                state.idcart[id] -= amount
            } else {
                Vue.delete(state.idcart, id)
            }

            localStorage.shoppingcart = JSON.stringify(state.idcart)
        }
    },

},

actions: {
    initStore: async ({commit}, id) => {.<секретные_запросы_AJAX>.}
    },

},

});
```

В компоненте ничего не поменялось, за исключением item[0] -> item['product'], и item[1] -> item['amount'] соответственно.

Проблема все же была в потере реактивности при присвоении промежуточного значения. То есть вроде бы сам state реактивный, а при выполнении промежуточных операций изменение переставало отслеживаться геттером.